# Javascript unknown number of arguments

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

in my project, I register different functions (having different number of arguments) as listeners to a number of events. When the event takes place, I need to fire the associated function. I receive the parameters to be passed to listener method in the form of an array whereas the listener function expect each separate argument. So, I am doing it like this but I do not like the approach and would like to know if there is an elegant way of doing it,

```
function callListenerWithArgs(func, args){
        switch(args.length){
            case 1:
                func(args[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                func(args[0], args[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                func(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                func(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
                break;
            default:
                func();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all guys. fun.apply does exactly what I needed. It is simple and sweet :) and addresses my problem precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .apply

```
func.apply(null, args)
```

If you need to bind to a specific scope, you can pass another argument in to use as `this` inside the function:

```
func.apply(scope, args);
```

Also, a nuance of JavaScript is that you can call functions with undefined values.  So making a small tweak to your existing code will work in 95% of all cases (this isn't suggested as a solution, just pointing it out):

```
// will handle any number of args up to 7
function callListenerWithArgs(func, args){
    func(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6]);
}
```

If your `func` is defined as:

```
function foo(a, b, c){
}
```

you get `a`, `b`, `c` passed in, along with some more `undefined` values that get ignored.  As I said above, this works in 95% of cases.  It doesn't work if you ever check `arguments.length` in the called function since it will always be the same, regardless of the number of parameters the function defines.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using [`function.apply`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx)

```
function callListenerWithArgs(func, args){
    func.apply(window, args);
}
```

Comment: .call doesn't take arrays.  .apply does

Comment: @cwolves. look at my answer again.

Comment: @cwolves i edited fast (before you commented) lol. somehow you saw it at the point where it was incorrect ^_^

Answer (score 1):

`functionName.apply(thisScope, arguments)` would be more elegant. The `arguments` argument must be an array.

You can build the Array like:

```
var args = [];

switch (arguments.length - 1) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        args.push(arguments[1]);
        break;
    case 2:
        args.push(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        break;
    case 3:
        args.push(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]);
        break;
    default:
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

or if the array is already built, just pass it as the second argument to .apply

Answer (score 1):

```
func.apply(this, args);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the number of arguments of a function:

```
var f = function ( ) { console.log(arguments.length); }
f( 2, 3 )  // > 2
```

That lets you implement your `func` function directly in place.

```
function func() {
  var nbArgs = arguments.length;
  // ...
}
```